# Excel: Data validation source

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list and I want to display certain data based on another cell value. Let's call it "cell A1".

In my logic, every value of "cell A1" means different list items.

The problem is when I added other values to the possible data that "cell A1" could contain, the formula becomes very long and couldn't fit in the source field!

For example, if "cell A1" possible values are Tigre, Dog, Cat, Lion, Horse, Sheep and Turkey, the condition is:

```
=IF(D4="Tigre";'Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$1000;IF(D4="Dog";'Sheet2'!$B$2:$B$1000;IF(D4="Cat";'Sheet3'!$B$2:$B$1000;IF(D4="Lion";'Sheet4'!$B$2:$B$1000; IF(D4=" Horse";'Sheet5'!$B$2:$B$1000;IF(D4="Sheep";'Sheet6'!$B$2:$B$1000;IF(D4=" Turkey";'Sheet7'!$B$2:$B$1000;IF(D4="Val8";'Sheet8'!$B$2:$B$1000;""))))))))))
```

[Check this image, the source field is already full! (before the end of the condition)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3dgE.png)
[image]

have you an idea how work around this issue or how to optimise the conditional formula?

PS: I'm a french user, so I apologize of my bad english! And, I know that I need to use "SI" instead of "IF" :)

Thanks.

Comment: ok, so elaborate on your condition setting, what kind of condition ? and do you have infinite sheets here ?

Comment: i mean if the value is just a crude format of 'valN' , extract the last letter and concatenate it with 'sheet'

Comment: Thanks for you answer!
Sorry if I wasn't clear, this is just an example!
"Real values" are NOT infinite and doesn't respect the 'ValN' format!

Comment: anis can you be more specific about your condition ?

Comment: I changed values! There is no relation between values and between values and sheets' names.

Comment: ok, why don't you arrange values (dog,cat,cow...) along one column=E then set INDIRECT('Sheet'&match(E:E,D4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be after something called dependent data validation.

Look here for a step by step tutorial http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.

Comment: dropdown solution is so infit

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your example, `Val1 Val2 etc.` are keys to redirect to specific worksheets. You can write the "mapping" data betweens these "Vals" and sheet names somewhere (possibly in a hidden worksheet or any available/hidden columns) and use it in the validation formula using a combination of `INDIRECT` and `VLOOKUP`. Say in this example I use Columns `G:H` in worksheet "mapping":

```
' Worksheet mapping
 G             H
Val 1       Sheet number 1
Value 2       Sheet2
Val3       My worksheet number 3
```

Now your data validation formula can be like this:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&VLOOKUP($D$4,mapping!$G$1:$H$3,2,0) &"'!$B2:$B1000")
```

p.s. you can then make the column `mapping!G1:G3` your data validation list for the cell `$D$4` that holds the keys.

I also notice here that if the ranges are not always the same (unlike in your example where they all are `B2:B1000`), you can also make the mapping "complete" by including the ranges in the redirection column (column H in my example).

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.